# webview in Android java

Tags: java, android, webview

I am converting a website into android app, when I put other URLs into Webview then the website is converting but when I put my URL into Webview its showing nothing.
That is url i am converting into mobile app:
[https://thealluniversity.com/][1]

```
 webView=findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://thealluniversity.com/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Dom Storage:

```
webView.settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: what is settings in it its showing error.

Comment: Good Luck! Waseem Akhtar